# Perl using Net::SFTP::Foreign get rid of server welcome message

Tags: perl, module, sftp, message

when I connect to a proFTP Server I get the welcome message printed to stdout.

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($sftserver);
```

Everything works fine, but how can I get rid of this message?

I don't want to pipe the whole script output to /dev/null  and I don't have access to the server's config.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `stderr_fh` option?

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `stderr_fh` option as documented:

> **stderr_fh => $fh**
>
> redirects the output sent to stderr by the SSH subprocess to the given file handle.
>
> It can be used to suppress banners:
>
> ```
> open my $ssherr, '>', '/dev/null' or die "unable to open /dev/null";
> my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host,
>                                stderr_fh => $ssherr);
> ```